# Is there an easy way to use clang with Open MPI?

Tags: clang, openmpi

OpenMPI [strongly recommends](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#general-build) using their wrapper compilers. Behind the scenes, their wrapper compiler mpiCC calls gcc (by default?) and adds the necessary flags for MPI code to compile. However, other compilers give more descriptive error messages than gcc (e.g. [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) which is also GCC-compatible). So, I'd like to be able to use clang with Open MPI.

I tried:

1) finding an mpiCC option for specifying the compiler, but

```
mpiCC --help
```

just spits out the g++ help page.

2) using the --showme:compile option

```
mpiCC --showme:compile ./test-boost.cc -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -o test-boost
```

which, instead of calling gcc, prints the flags needed for compiling the MPI code. I can then use those with clang (since it's GCC-compatible). This should work, but I'm looking for an easier solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open MPI FAQ says which environmental variables can be set to override the default choice of the compiler called by the wrapper.

http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#override-wrappers-after-v1.0

Depending on the version of OpenMPI you should set `OMPI_CXX=clang++` or `OMPI_MPICC=clang`. For OpenMPI v.1.1 and later use `OMPI_CXX` and then call the wrapper compiler. The wrapper would call clang++ in turn.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work if you need to use multiple "wrapper" compilers, e.g. `nvcc` + `mpicc`. E.g. `OMPI_CXX=clang++ nvcc -ccbin mpicc` ultimately uses `g++` as the host compiler, so `OMPI_CXX` seems to be lost somewhere along the way...

Answer (score 2):

Setting `OMPI_CC=clang` or `OMPI_CXX=clang++` as environment variables in `.bashrc`, as described in the official FAQ of OpenMPI, is NOT working for me. I have to attach them ahead whenever I use `mpicc`, e.g.

```
OMPI_CC=clang mpicc --showme:command
```

So in `Makefile`, I set `CC=OMPI_CC=clang mpicc`, which works well for me.

Comment: Did you `export` the variables?

Comment: @Rufflewind Yes, but it doesn't work on my mac (OS X 10.10). BTW, I use `.profile` to configure bash, instead of `.bashrc` (for certain reasons, I have forgotten). Maybe this is the reason.

Comment: Bash does not read `~/.profile` if `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` are already present.

Comment: @Rufflewind Thanks! I don't have any other configuration files of bash, like `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`. Well, maybe mine is a special case, it could a conflict against other configurations/settings somewhere I don't know.